# How to vectorize comparison in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have a part of dataframe `df` like this:

```
| nr | Time | Event |
|----|------|-------|
| 70 | 8    |       |
| 70 | 0    |       |
| 70 | 0    |       |
| 74 | 52   |       |
| 74 | 12   |       |
| 74 | 0    |       |
```

I want to assign events to the last column. The first entry is 1 by default.

```
If Time[i] < 7 and nr[i] != nr[i-1], then Event[i]=Event[i-1]+1. 

If Time[i] < 7 and nr[i] = nr[i-1], then Event[i]=Event[i-1]

If Time[i] > 7 then Event[i]=Event[i-1]+1.
```

How do I effectively vectorize this? I want to avoid loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your definition of your conditions, you define the outputs as being dependent on past inputs.  Usually this requires iteration.  However, if you think about your outputs a bit differently, and instead just consider what the *change* in value is (1 or 0), you can vectorize this with `numpy.select`.

In general:

- If the first condition is met, increase the Series by 1
- If the second condition is met, leave the Series the same
- Otherwise, increase the Series by 1

---

```
t = df.Time.lt(7)
n = df.nr.ne(df.nr.shift())

o = np.select([t & n, t & ~n], [1, 0], 1)
o[0] = 1                               # You say first value is 1
df.assign(Event=o.cumsum())
```

```
   nr  Time  Event
0  70     8      1
1  70     0      1
2  70     0      1
3  74    52      2
4  74    12      3
5  74     0      3
```

Comment: `t = df.Time.lt(7); n = df.nr.ne(df.nr.shift()); np.select([t & n, t & ~n], [1, 0], 1)` Maybe?

Comment: Yep, definitely cleaner and more efficient

Comment: @user3483203: Can the above tweak be handled too?

Comment: I was trying something like this: 

    m = df.Machine.ne(df.Machine.shift())
    o = np.select([t & n, t & ~n, m], [1, 0, 1], 1)

But that doesn't reset the Event for a new machine to 1, I realized. @piRSquared: Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You have three conditions. I note though you don't have any criteria for when Time == 7?

That said, two of your three criteria add 1 to the previous Event. So start by making column 'Event' equal to 1 and then change value for the third criteria.

```
df['Event'] = 1

   nr  Time  Event
0  70     8      1
1  70     0      1
2  70     0      1
3  74    52      1
4  74    12      1
5  74     0      1
```

Then filter for the other criteria and set 'Event' to 0

```
df.loc[(df['Time'] < 7) & (df['nr'] == df['nr'].shift(1)), 'Event'] = 0

  nr  Time  Event
0  70     8      1
1  70     0      0
2  70     0      0
3  74    52      1
4  74    12      1
5  74     0      0
```

Then cumsum()

```
df['Event'] = df['Event'].cumsum()

   nr  Time  Event
0  70     8      1
1  70     0      1
2  70     0      1
3  74    52      2
4  74    12      3
5  74     0      3
```