# Vectorizing comparison in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

An earlier version of the question was answered here:

[How to vectorize comparison in pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56135316/how-to-vectorize-comparison-in-pandas-dataframe)

Now, I've added a new condition with `Machine`:

```
+---------+-----+-------+---------+
| Machine | nr  |  Time |   Event |
+---------+-----+-------+---------+
| a       |  70 |     8 |    1    |
| a       |  70 |     0 |    1    |
| b       |  70 |     0 |    1    |
| c       |  74 |    52 |    1    |
| c       |  74 |    12 |    2    |
| c       |  74 |     0 |    2    |
+---------+-----+-------+---------+
```

I want to assign events to the last column. The first entry of each `Machine` is 1 by default. That is, if it's a new `Machine`, the `Event` restarts from 1.

```
If Time[i] < 7 and nr[i] != nr[i-1], then Event[i]=Event[i-1]+1. 

If Time[i] < 7 and nr[i] = nr[i-1], then Event[i]=Event[i-1]

If Time[i] > 7 then Event[i]=Event[i-1]+1.
```

How do I effectively vectorize this? I want to avoid loops. 
I try to augment the existing solution with

```
m = df.Machine.ne(df.Machine.shift()) 
o = np.select([t & n, t & ~n, m], [1, 0, 1], 1)
```

But that doesn't reset the `Event` for a new `Machine` to 1, I realized, only augments it. Any pointers on how to incorporate this?

Comment: What output are you getting? What are you expecting the output to look like instead?

Comment: @PMende: I've added on how the output should look like.

Comment: I've added an answer that should does what you're looking for if I understand your requirements.

Comment: @PMende: It doesn't meet the original conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developing from your previous solution. It looks correct on your sample:

```
t = df.Time.lt(7)
n = df.nr.ne(df.nr.shift())
m = df.Machine.ne(df.Machine.shift()) 

df['Event'] = np.select([m | t & n, t & ~n], [1, 0], 1)
df['Event'] = df.groupby('Machine').Event.cumsum()

Out[279]:
  Machine  nr  Time  Event
0       a  70     8      1
1       a  70     0      1
2       b  70     0      1
3       c  74    52      1
4       c  74    12      2
5       c  74     0      2
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should produce the output you're looking for:

```py
# Given you have a dataframe as df
# Create a series for grouping and looking for consecutive runs
mach_nr = df["Machine"] + df["nr"].astype("str")
mach_nr_runs = mach_nr.eq(mach_nr.shift())
# Groupby consecutive runs of each 'Machine'/'nr' combination by its
# that combination value, and take the cumulative sum of the equality
# of shifted combinations
df["Event"] = (
    mach_nr_runs.groupby(mach_nr)
                .cumsum()
                .astype("int")
                .add(1)
)
# Correct the rows where there were consecutive runs, and where 'Time' < 7
lt_7_runs = (df["Time"] < 7) & mach_nr_runs
df["Event"] -= (
    lt_7_runs.groupby(mach_nr)
              .cumsum()
              .astype("int")
)
```

`df` now looks like the following:

```
  Machine  nr  Time  Event
0       a  70     8      1
1       a  70     0      1
2       b  70     0      1
3       c  74    52      1
4       c  74    12      2
5       c  74     0      2
```

Answer (score 0):

In the light of your previous question (and its excellent answer), you can do `groupby('machine')` and apply the function as if you only have one data frame.

```
def get_event(x):
    t = x.Time.lt(7)
    n = x.nr.ne(x.nr.shift())

    o = np.select([t & n, t & ~n], [1, 0], 1)
    o[0] = 1                               # You say first value is 1
    return pd.Series(o.cumsum(), index=x.index)


df['Event'] = df.groupby('Machine', group_keys=False).apply(get_event)
```